# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.dates' has no attribute '_rcParam_helper'

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I am trying to import matlibplot or sns or plotly packages below is the error

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.dates' has no attribute '_rcParam_helper'.

I have tried to install older versions but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is an installation issue where you have more than one version of Matplotlib installed at the same time so some files are from one version and some are from another (a chimera).

I suggest uninstalling *everything* and starting again clean with exactly one package management tool (pip vs conda vs system vs ...).

In https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/814a969d4a731321827a108c38ed6f3aaf50a623 (which looks like it went in between 3.4.2 and 3.5.0) we re-named an internal class.  I suspect you have a new version of `dates.py` and an old version of `rcsetup.py`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have uninstalled and removed Matplotlib from the system.